# Can a database be added to an HA group online?

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

*Edited*

I created a new database on my HA server and I need to add it the to availability group. It's a new database and doesn't have anything in it. The HA group contains multiple critical databases running in it.

Can I add the new database to the HA group without affecting the currently running databases? Will it bring down the HA during the operation?

Didn't find that info on msdn.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new database to an existing availability group without impact to the AG and little impact to the affected database. I'm not saying "no impact to the database" because as soon as you add the database to the AG, the rules of clearing the transaction log for databases in an AG apply. Which means that you'll need to have a plan to get any secondary replicas in sync with the primary ASAP.

Comment: Good thx.
I don't care for the added database impact. I'm more concerned with the impact on the databases already in the availability group.